# Single List or list of lists json parsing failing

Tags: scala, akka-http, spray-json

I have a json that sometimes returns `List[List[x, y], List[a, b]]` or if there is only one then `List[x, y]` ?

My case class defines

```
case class Geometry(dataType: String, coordinates: List[List[BigDecimal]])
```

Exception in thread "main"

```
spray.json.DeserializationException:
  Expected List as JsArray, but got x when there is only one list List[x,y]
```

How can I define such a json response. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add an example of the JSON - you want to deserialize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Either` to encapsulate both possibilities:

```
case class Geometry(
  dataType: String,
  coordinates: Either[List[BigDecimal], List[List[BigDecimal]]]
)
```